# Removing element from arraylist inside recyclerview adapter, NotifyDatasetChanged inside the OnBindViewHolder Method

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am using Github library StepperTouch in my recyclerview layout. Inside my adapter, I am trying to remove an element from the array list when the stepper is zero or change the value of the element inside the array list when the value is increased or decreased. 
Problem is as to how to notify the adapter of the change inside my `bindviewholder()` method
below is my adapter

```
public class MyCartAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCartAdapter.MyCartViewHolder>{
private List<AllItems> listItems1;
private Context context;

public MyCartAdapter(List<AllItems> listItems1, Context context) {
    this.listItems1 = listItems1;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyCartAdapter.MyCartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cart_items_layout, parent, false);
    return new MyCartViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyCartAdapter.MyCartViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    final AllItems orderItem = listItems1.get(position);
    holder.setProductImage(orderItem.getImageUrl(),context);
    holder.name.setText(orderItem.getName());
    holder.setStepper(context);
    holder.stepperTouch.setCount(Integer.parseInt(orderItem.getQuantity()));
    String price = String.valueOf(orderItem.getPrice());
    holder.price.setText(price);
    holder.setComname(orderItem.getComname());

    final HashMap<String, AllItems> items = ((UserMainActivity)context).getItemMap();

    holder.stepperTouch.addStepCallback(new OnStepCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStep(int value, boolean positive) {
            int count = holder.stepperTouch.getCount();
            if (count==0){
                AllItems item = items.get(orderItem.getName());
                if (item!=null){
                    String orderit = orderItem.getName();
                    ((UserMainActivity)context).removeItem(orderit);
                    listItems1.remove(position);
                }
            }
            else {
                    String quantity = String.valueOf(holder.stepperTouch.getCount());
                    String orderitemname = orderItem.getName();
                    String url = orderItem.getImageUrl();
                    String weight = orderItem.getWeight();
                    AllItems newitem = new AllItems(orderitemname ,orderItem.getComname(),url, quantity,weight,orderItem.getPrice());
                    ((UserMainActivity)context).addItem(orderitemname,newitem);
                    listItems1.set(position, newitem);
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return listItems1.size();

}


public class MyCartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name,price,count,comname;
    public TextView weight;
    public ImageView productImage;

    public MyCartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProName);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proPrice);
        weight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProWeight);
    }

    public void setProductImage(final String thumb_image, final Context ctx){

        productImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProImage);
        Picasso.with(ctx).setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
        Picasso.with(ctx)
                .load(thumb_image)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.basket_b).into(productImage, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.basket).into(productImage);
            }
        });
}


    public void setComname(String name){
        comname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.proComName);
        comname.setText(name);
    }
    public void setStepper(final Context context){
        stepperTouch = (StepperTouch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stepper);
        stepperTouch.setMinValue(0);
        stepperTouch.setMaxValue(9);
        stepperTouch.setSideTapEnabled(true);
    }
    StepperTouch stepperTouch;
}
```

}

i have tried using `MyCartAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();` but its showing error.
    Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

the above code works for removing but I can not do the `notifyDatasetChanged()` inside the bindview method is there any way to use `notifydatasetChanged()` in this case.

Comment: can you share your adapter whole code

Comment: i have updated the code please check the code above

Comment: use `listItems1.removeAt(position);` instead of `listItems1.remove(position);` and then notify your `recyclerview` and 
`listItems1.add(position, newitem);` instead of `listItems1.set(position, newitem);`

Comment: But how do i notify my recyclerview ?

Comment: its adapter you are going to notify

Comment: removeAt is not a function

Comment: Notifydatasetchanged() inside the onBindViewHolder method is showing an error, i have written above the problem is i am unable to notify the adapter

Comment: Removing the item is not the issue. The problem is how do i notify the adapter inside the bindviewholder method

Comment: Can you show your class StepperTouch,when will the onStep method be triggered?

Comment: its an external library that i am using here is the link https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Stepper-Touch

Answer (score 1):

try running it on UI thread

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
  // UI code goes here
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more on how & where should i do it.

Comment: did you tried notify data if not please call notifyDataSetChanged() after this line  listItems1.remove(position)

Comment: yes i have tried after remove() method but its showing an error cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the scope of your `Adapter`, but rather of your `OnStepCallback`. To access your adapter's scope you can try : `YourAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Comment: Is there any other way of calling notifyDataSetChanged inside the onBindViewHolder() method of adapter.